# EF Rename Column in MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to rename a column via a migration in my MySql database.

This is my migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
   //RenameColumn("Docks", "ProfileId", "SecondId"); <!-- doesn't work either
   RenameColumn("Docks", "ProfileId", "SecondId", anonymousArguments: new { ColumnType = "int" });
}

public override void Down()
{
   //RenameColumn("Docks", "SecondId", "ProfileId"); <!-- doesn't work either
   RenameColumn("Docks", "SecondId", "ProfileId", anonymousArguments:  new { ColumnType = "int" });
}
```

When I run `Update-Database` It spews a large error out at me (if you want to see the whole error, open the snippet), which includes:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Parameter '@columnType' must be defined.

```html
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException(0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution.-- - > MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException(0x80004005): Parameter '@columnType' must be defined. at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection
parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.
< NonQuery> b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext `1 c) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher` 1. Dispatch[TTarget, TInterceptionContext, TResult](TTarget target, Func `3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
  Action` 3 executing, Action `3 executed) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement
  migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable` 1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction
  transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable `1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`
  1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable `1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable` 1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.
  <> c__DisplayClass32.
    < ExecuteStatements> b__30() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable `1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`
      1 migrationStatements) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable `1 migrationStatements) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel,
      IEnumerable` 1 operations, IEnumerable `1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
      migration, DbMigration lastMigration) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable` 1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable
      `1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.
      <>c__DisplayClasse.
        <Update>b__d() at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
          targetMigration) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore() at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
          Fatal error encountered during command execution.
```

Verbose mode generated the following sql query prior to throwing the error:

```
set @columnType := (select  case lower(IS_NULLABLE)
                            when 'no' then CONCAT(column_type, ' not null ')
                            when 'yes' then column_type end
    from  information_schema.columns
    where  table_name = 'Docks'
      and  column_name = 'ProfileId');
set @sqlstmt := (select concat('alter table `Docks`
                      change `ProfileId` `SecondId` ' , @columnType));
prepare stmt from @sqlstmt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

I was curious, so I copy and pasted the sql into the db and it executed as expected without errors and successfully renamed the column with the correct type of `int(11)`.

So how do I prevent this error from throwing even though it is generating (apparently) valid sql?

---

**Edit:** Wanted to note that the accepted answer here worked for me even though I was not using dotconnect.

Comment: Are you sure you are targeting the correct database with EF? If the database schema is not correct, the first query will return NULL and therefore will deliver incorrect syntax and should throw exactly the error you are seeing.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Well all of my migrations to date have worked and the application does work currently.

Comment: What was the SQL generated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found solution of above issue: (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException):  as far as I understand it is related to an upgrade of the connector.

You need to add `Allow User Variables=True` in the connection string in order to use custom variables.

Follow this link for your reference :

http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19169281)

Comment: I am new user to this site so dont have that much understanding of following standards .still will keep in mind.

Comment: @Mrunalini the reviewer is suggesting you should improve your answer by copying the relevant information from your link i.e. code snippet and then post it within your answer. The reason for this is that if that link goes dead then all information making your post relevant will be lost.

Comment: Sure will improve way of answering questions .

Comment: Thank you - This solved the issue for me, even though I am not using dotconnect, which is interesting.

Comment: @Zze glad to hear that..:)

Answer (score 0):

Up and down take the same column types. I assume that you want to change only column name. I wonder you can try without anonymousArguments like that:

```
public override void Up()
{
    // RenameColumn("Docks", "ProfileId", "SecondId"); // old answer
    RenameColumn("Docks", "ProfileId", "SecondId", anonymousArguments: new { columnType = "int" });
}

public override void Down()
{
    // RenameColumn("Docks", "SecondId", "ProfileId"); // old answer
    RenameColumn("Docks", "SecondId", "ProfileId", anonymousArguments: new { columnType = "int" });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this as well and it does not work. Thanks for the answer, I will make it better known in my question that I have attempted this.

Comment: Could you try it (ColumnType) in small letters like 'columnType' if I ask? I edit my answer

Comment: I will attempt this when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

When `ALTERing` a column, you must specify the entire definition, not just the one thing you want to change.  You left out the datatype (INT), and possibly other things.

I suggest you get the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, modify the one line in question, then use that in `ALTER`.  Though messy, it is probably still easier than trying to reconstruct the full description of the field in question.

In practice, it is simply easier to do the task manually, not programatically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the syntax I need to include the dataType.

Comment: I added to my answer.